# Replace in matrix at given indices

Tags: matrix, replacement

How to replace a term at defined indices of a matrix?

The expression

`{{a, b, c}, {a, b, c}} /. c -> d`

replaces both c but for this example I want to replace only at index (2,3) an the result shall be

`{{a, b, c}, {a, b, d}}`

Comment: `ReplaceAt[{{a, b, c}, {a, b, d}}, c -> d, {2, 3}]`

Comment: Also: `ReplacePart[{{a, b, c}, {a, b, d}}, {2, 3} -> d]`